# How to implement SEG (Wootton and Federhen ,1993) algorithm?

Tags: r, python, sequence-analysis, protein-structure, matlab

I want to implement SEG in my MATLAB environment and I'm relying on Wootton and Federhen ([1993](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/009784859385006X))
Reading the article I cannot succeed to understand what kind of process I have to implement in order to build my script. Specifically what kind of statistics I should follow to compute the complexity state and the repetition vector and what kind of procedure I have to do to calculate these statistics over the amino acid sequence.

Do you know some articles that explains in a better fashion what is needed, namely the mathematical process behind the results shown in the article? Code examples in other languages welcome.
Thank you in advance

Comment: You might want to be more specific here. What part are you struggling with in that paper?  At a glance it appears well explained —no mathemagic. Or is converting summations &co. to quick vector calculus Matlab without for-loops or converting a string (cell of characters) to a vector, which in Matlab is annoying?

Comment: It is not a problem about the code. It is a problem about the various passages that I should follow. Basically, reading the article, it is not very clear about what kind of statistics I should follow to compute the complexity state and the repetition vector and what kind of procedure I have to do to calculate these statistics over the amino acid sequence. The article is not very clear and I was searching for some more detailed threads to follow in order to understand what I have to do in whatever programming language.

Comment: I edited your question accordingly and to nudge it back to the top —comments do not trigger this.